# Under what circumstances will nhibernate run queries without parameters?

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

During a pen-test of an in-development app, I had a scary result where there was a successful SQL injection due to NH executing a query without parameters and instead injecting a string right into the query.

We're using NHibernate 4 and Fluent NHibernate 1.4.  Dialect is SQL 2008 running against SQL Azure.

The successful query looked like this (pulled from SQL Azure audit logs)

`select columns from [Table] table0_ where table0_.TenantId='1555%00';IF(5672=5672) SELECT 5672 ELSE DROP FUNCTION GziQ--' and table0_.Active=1`

As you can see, the injectable string was able to terminate the string and inject a DROP FUNCTION then comment out the rest of the statement.

Running this locally and using NHibernate Profiler, we see the value being passed as a parameter as-expected:

`select columns from [Table] table0_ where table0_.TenantId = @p0 and table0_.Active=1`

On the code side, the data is queried using an IQueryable interface (code inlined and simplified for example purposes):

```
Session.Query<TEntityType>().Cachable().Table.SingleOrDefault(k => k.TenantId == tenantId && k.Active);
```

Under what circumstanes would NHibernate not parameterize this query and instead inject the string directly into a plain SQL statement?

Comment: What linq provider are you using?

Comment: NHibnerate.Linq namespace is included with NH 4.0.

Comment: That's weird, I haven't seen it do that before. The Azure dialect is almost exactly the same as the regular SQL Server 2008 dialect. To clarify, did the injection actually execute the DROP FUNCTION (to rule out that just the logging is being deparameterized)?

Comment: Yes @OskarBerggren, Azure Audit log shows a schema change execution due to the drop function.  I've followed up with the azure team I'm working with to determine if it's at all possible there was some sort of logging error, but I think that is unlikely. Also, this was a single occurrences like this, other attempts were properly parameterized and logged as so.